# Why does infinite sum of finite summands converge in this proof $\sum 1/p$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

In this proof from  the university of Warwick ([pdf](http://www.warwickmaths.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/75_-The-Distribution-of-Prime-Numbers-and-the-Gaps-Between-Primes.pdf)) there is a step which assumes the infinite sum of finite summands converges.

Why is this?

I can see why each summand $\sum_p1/p^s$ for $s \geq 2$ converges, but not why an infinite sum of these.

[image]

Comment: Well, $\sum p^{-n-1}$ is at most $\frac12$ times $\sum p^{-n}$. So we have a geometric series as an upper bound to that sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a good question that is not obvious (at least in my mind). Luckily, it is not to difficult to show something even stronger:

$$\sum_{s=2}^\infty \sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{sp^s}<\sum_{s=2}^\infty \sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{p^s}<\sum_{s=2}^\infty \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$

Since these terms are all positive, **if** the series converges it must converge absolutely. Thus, we are free to switch the order of summations without effecting the overall convergence or divergence. Then

$$=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1$$

We conclude the overall series is bounded and hence converges.